# How to create akka-http cachedHostConnectionPool for https requests in scala?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I can't figure out how to create `cachedHostConnectionPool` in akka-http using scala for sending `https` requests. `queueRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "https://example.com")` sends a request to http, `cachedHostConnectionPool[Promise[HttpResponse]]("https://example.com")` throws an error that `:` isn't expected character.

```
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, Promise }

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

import akka.stream.{ OverflowStrategy, QueueOfferResult }

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
import system.dispatcher // to get an implicit ExecutionContext into scope
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val QueueSize = 10

// This idea came initially from this blog post:
// http://kazuhiro.github.io/scala/akka/akka-http/akka-streams/2016/01/31/connection-pooling-with-akka-http-and-source-queue.html
val poolClientFlow = Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[Promise[HttpResponse]]("example.com")
val queue =
  Source.queue[(HttpRequest, Promise[HttpResponse])](QueueSize, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
    .via(poolClientFlow)
    .toMat(Sink.foreach({
      case ((Success(resp), p)) => p.success(resp)
      case ((Failure(e), p))    => p.failure(e)
    }))(Keep.left)
    .run()

def queueRequest(request: HttpRequest): Future[HttpResponse] = {
  val responsePromise = Promise[HttpResponse]()
  queue.offer(request -> responsePromise).flatMap {
    case QueueOfferResult.Enqueued    => responsePromise.future
    case QueueOfferResult.Dropped     => Future.failed(new RuntimeException("Queue overflowed. Try again later."))
    case QueueOfferResult.Failure(ex) => Future.failed(ex)
    case QueueOfferResult.QueueClosed => Future.failed(new RuntimeException("Queue was closed (pool shut down) while running the request. Try again later."))
  }
}

val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = queueRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "/"))
```

It seems like scala version supports only plain host names while in java you can provide a protocol too (from their tests):

```
http.cachedHostConnectionPool("akka.io", materializer());
http.cachedHostConnectionPool("https://akka.io", materializer());
http.cachedHostConnectionPool("https://akka.io:8080", materializer());
```

Any known workarounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/HttpExt.html#cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps[T](host:String,port:Int,connectionContext:akka.http.scaladsl.HttpsConnectionContext,settings:akka.http.scaladsl.settings.ConnectionPoolSettings,log:akka.event.LoggingAdapter)(implicitfm:akka.stream.Materializer):akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[(akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest,T),(scala.util.Try[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse],T),akka.http.scaladsl.Http.HostConnectionPool]) instead:

```
val poolClientFlow = Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps[Promise[HttpResponse]]("example.com")
```